Android TextView typing imitation - problem with text jumping
I have TextView where text is appearing slowly imitating that it was typed in. It works great but I want to get rid of jumping text which happens every time when word is wrapping to the new line.
Here is what I mean:
https://youtube.com/shorts/9FzEIjpPECw
I understand why this happens, but I don't see how I can prevent this. Other than disable word wrapping, but then the text won't look right (I don't want a word to start on one line and continue on the next). It even happens when I change my code to imitate typing word-by-word, not letter-by-letter. Letter-by-letter actually looks much better, and I would love to keep it.
I would like to get any suggestions/recommendation how to solve this. Thank you!
And here's my code (commented out part is for word-by-word typing):
private void typeText() {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
            if (!isAdded()) return;
            if (currentMessagePos++ >= currentMessage.length()) {
                messageTextView.setText(currentMessage);
                onTypeCompleted();
                return;
            }
            messageTextView.setText(currentMessage.substring(0, currentMessagePos));

//            int p = currentMessage.indexOf(" ", currentMessagePos + 1);
//            if (p != -1 && p - currentMessagePos < 3)
//                p = currentMessage.indexOf(" ", p + 1);
//            if (p == -1) {
//                messageTextView.setText(currentMessage);
//                onTypeCompleted();
//                return;
//            }
//            messageTextView.setText(currentMessage.substring(0, p));
//            currentMessagePos = p;
            typeText();
        }, 20);
    }


I found an elegant solution which completely solves the text jumping problem. I use SpannableString to make some characters invisible. Initially all characters are invisible, but the whole string already fills the TextView so it doesn't have to re-wrap text when the next character appears. During the process the characters becomes visible one by one, making impression that the text is typing in. Here is the final code:
    private void typeText() {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
            if (!isAdded()) return;

            if (currentMessagePos++ >= currentMessage.length()) {
                messageTextView.setText(currentMessage);
                onTypeCompleted();
                return;
            }

            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(currentMessage);
            @ColorInt int transparentColor = ContextCompat.getColor(MafiaApp.getContext(), R.color.transparent);
            Object what = new ForegroundColorSpan(transparentColor);
            spannableString.setSpan(what, currentMessagePos, currentMessage.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            messageTextView.setText(spannableString);

            typeText();
        }, 20);
    }


